# Calculating first moments of inertia of an object using Divergance theorem

Tags: integration

I have a polyhedron that I need to calculate its first moments of inertia $\mathbf{Q}=\int\int\int_V \mathbf{r} dV$. Is there any way to calculate these using Divergance theorem? I use that theorem to calculate volume of the polyhedra like this:

$
V = \int\int\int_V dv 
  = \int\int\int_V \frac{1}{3}\nabla.\mathbf{r} dv
  = \frac{1}{3} \int\int_S \mathbf{r} . d\mathbf{s}
  = \frac{1}{3} \sum_S \mathbf{r}_c . \mathbf{n} A
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the divergence theorem the integrand of the volume integral is an scalar. Your integrand is vectorial, but *each* component is an scalar.

Comment: Consider the problem as $Q_x=\int\int\int_V x dv$. How to integrate this using divergence theorem?

Comment: Find a vector field $F$ s. t. div $F=x$.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I just want to say it was not important if I used the vector form.